# Issue in Linq to object where clause : the condition is bypassed

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

Hi everyone,

Today it is my first post on my favourite C# helping ressources web site. I'm glade to join the community.

Here is my problem, I would like to call .Select linq clause to create a list of a struct after filtering a list of double values with the .Where clause, but the filtering conditions don't seem being evaluated or they return always true.
Please view my code to well understand the issue :

```cs
string[] msgNames = new string[] { "de", "vf", "ze", "ki", "vt", "er" };
double[] prevCounters = new double[] { 154.0, 24588.0, 4547.0, 788.0, 1455.0, 24577.0 };
double[] counters = new double[] { 8548.0, 54854.0, 54854.0, 44.0, 121.0, 48547.0 };
double[] lenValues = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 4.0, 5.0, 0.0 };

BufferInfo[] positiveLenValues = counters
    .Where((c, it) => lenValues[it] >= 1.0 && prevCounters[it] != c)
    .Select((c, it) =>
    {
        prevCounters[it] = c;

        return new BufferInfo()
        {
            Name = msgNames[it],
            Length = lenValues[it]
        };
    }).ToArray();
```

Perhaps I misunderstood the linq usage, but at the end the returned BufferInfo[] contains all the values while there are some values less than 1.0 in the lenValues array. For information there is no concurrent access to this code block.. The local variables over the linq bloc are usually instanciated dynamically (retuned by an external assembly, from National Instruments), it's here just for you to know.

For example, the same bahaviour but with a for loop, works as well :

```cs
List<BufferInfo> myInfos = new List<BufferInfo>();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (lenValues[i] >= 1.0 && prevCounters[i] != counters[i])
    {
        oldCounters[i] = counters[i];
        myInfos.Add(new BufferInfo()
                    {
                        Length = lenValues[i],
                        Name = msgNames[i]
                    });
    }
}

BufferInfo[] buffers = myInfos.ToArray();
```

I don't care to use linq or not, I just want to understand why it fails.
Please explain me why i've got these strange results.

Best regards,
Lun@ir.

Comment: Use the `for` loop. It's arguably clearer than the Linq version in this case, and you're embedding a mutation in your `Select`, which doesn't fit the standard expectation of Linq (that it filters, projects, aggregates, etc., but otherwise leaves source data unmodified).

Comment: Anthony is right; making a select clause which *modifies stuff* is a worst practice. A query should just *ask questions* about data, it should not *change* data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's because your `.Select((c, it) =>` starts its index from 0 again...

So if your `Where` clause filters items and returns only 4 items, your `Select` will use indexes `0, 1, 2, 3` which doesn't correspond to the indexes of the items you returned with `Where`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code don't even compile, so I have no idea how you tested that it's no working ...

You have to write `Select` to get indexes first, and then pass it into `Where` method:

```
BufferInfo[] positiveLenValues = counters.Select((c, i) => new { c, i })
                                         .Where(e => lenValues[e.i] >= 1.0 && prevCounters[e.i] != e.c)
                                         .Select(e =>
                                         {
                                             prevCounters[e.i] = e.c;
                                             return new BufferInfo
                                             {
                                                 Name = msgNames[e.i],
                                                 Length = lenValues[e.i]
                                             };
                                         }).ToArray();
```

That code returns 4 values, what is predicable and seems to be correct result.

Comment: Yes, just realized that. Updated my answer.

Comment: Replace BufferInfo[] by var and "return new Buffer" by "return new"